# Problem with UI update and window freezing when using Dispatcher class in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

I am trying to add `ProgressBar` for data `loading`. I would like to print which how many data I need to load before AdminWindow is showed (the window is showed when there is no data to load). The problems are two:

1. **I don't see the text as such**.
   I have tried to solve it using class `Dispatcher`:

   ```
      public void UpdateProgress(int processedEmails, int totalEmails)
      {
       // Update text and progress bar on a thread that has its own UI
       Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
       {
           // Text Update
           txtProgress.Text = $"Remains to load {totalEmails - processedEmails} from {totalEmails} newly saved";

           // Calculating and updating progress (this is a simple example where progress is expressed as a percentage)

           double progressPercentage = (double)processedEmails / totalEmails * 100;
           progressBar.Value = progressPercentage;

           // When all data is loaded, display the AdminWindow and hide the ProgressWindow
           if (processedEmails == totalEmails)
           {
               admin.Show();
               Hide();
           }
       });
     }
   ```

or with `async` and `Task`

```
 public async Task UpdateProgressAsync(int processedEmails, int totalEmails)
        {
           
            await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                // same code
            }
         }
```

**Implementation:**

```
private async Task ProcessEmails()
        {
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
               

               
                int processedEmailsCount = 0; // Počet zpracovaných emailů
                int totalEmailsCount = uids.Count; // Celkový počet emailů k zpracování

                foreach (var uid in uids)
                {
                  
                        foreach (var item in FindResult(GetBodyText, message))
                        {
                           
                            Save(item);

                            processedEmailsCount++; // 
                              
                         }

                       }
                  }
                    inbox.AddFlags(uid, MessageFlags.Seen, true);

                    // ProgressWindow status update
                    await progress.UpdateProgressAsync(processedEmailsCount, totalEmailsCount);

                    if (totalEmailsCount == 0)
                    {
                        OnAdminWindowReady();
                    }
                   
                }

                client.Disconnect(true);

               
            }
        }


// Event for loading saved data from database
protected virtual void OnAdminWindowReady()
        {
            AdminWindowReady?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

2. Both **windows are freezed**
   When I used `Dispatcher`, it just displayed a white frozen window after loading the data.

When I used `async` and `Task`, the window displayed fine, but still frozen

Comment: "*Update text and progress bar on a thread that has its own UI*" - that is a misconception. The Dispatcher marshals the passed Action to the main UI thread. It does not create any "background UI thread".

Comment: @Clemens Okay, but it still does not point on my problem. Or does it?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to the duplicate question. You would have an update method that runs in a Task Action and reports progress via the IProgress interface.